# calculate distance between regression line and datapoint

Tags: r, plot, distance

I wonder if there is a  way to calculate the distance between a abline in a plot and a datapoint? For example,  what is the distance between `concentration == 40` with `signal == 643` (element 5) and the abline?

```
concentration <- c(1,10,20,30,40,50)
signal <- c(4, 22, 44, 244, 643, 1102)
plot(concentration, signal)
res <- lm(signal ~ concentration)
abline(res)
```

Comment: Do you mean the shortest distance to the line or the vertical distance (distance between observed and fitted value)? If the latter, then look at `?residuals`

Comment: @James: Yours is the key question.  There are now two answers, and either is correct depending on what Lisann is asking for.

Comment: The shortest distance to the line are the residuals of [Total Least Squares Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares).

Comment: @cbeleites: True, but do you really want to run TLS regression just to get a simple answer?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, for my problem i need the vertival distance

Comment: @gsk3: I don't know - I just thought that looking for the shortest distance may be the symptom of the errors in x and y being of the same order of magnitude. Then I'd do a TLS, as I do an inverse OLS if the concentration errors are larger than the signal errors (which is in fact often the case).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are basically asking for the `residuals`.

```
R> residuals(res)
      1       2       3       4       5       6 
 192.61   12.57 -185.48 -205.52  -26.57  212.39
```

As an aside, when you fit a linear regression, the sum of the residuals is 0:

```
R> sum(residuals(res))
[1] 8.882e-15
```

and if the model is correct, should follow a Normal distribution - `qqnorm(res)`.

I find working with the standardised residuals easier.

```
> rstandard(res)
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
 1.37707  0.07527 -1.02653 -1.13610 -0.15845  1.54918
```

These residuals have been scaled to have mean zero, variance (approximately) equal to one and have a Normal distribution. Outlying standardised residuals are those larger that +/- 2.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, especially as you've answered the question asked, but users should realize this solution applies for residuals of the fitted data.  Application to new points requires the difference between the y value and the output of `predict`, aka y-hat.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function below:

http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/pointline.r

Then just extract the slope and intercept:

```
> coef(res)
  (Intercept) concentration 
   -210.61098      22.00441
```

So your final answer would be:

```
concentration <- c(1,10,20,30,40,50)
signal <- c(4, 22, 44, 244, 643, 1102)
plot(concentration, signal)
res <- lm(signal ~ concentration)
abline(res)
```

[image: plot]

```
cfs <- coef(res)
distancePointLine(y=signal[5], x=concentration[5], slope=cfs[2], intercept=cfs[1])
```

If you want a more general solution to finding a particular point, `concentration == 40` returns a Boolean vector of length `length(concentration)`.  You can use that vector to select points.

```
pt.sel <- ( concentration == 40 )
> pt.sel
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
> distancePointLine(y=signal[pt.sel], x=concentration[pt.sel], slope=cfs["concentration"], intercept=cfs["(Intercept)"])
     1.206032
```

Unfortunately distancePointLine doesn't appear to be vectorized (or it does, but it returns a warning when you pass it a vector).  Otherwise you could get answers for all points just by leaving the [] selector off the x and y arguments.

Comment: The link to the function seems dead

Comment: Unfortunately it appears broken and isn't in the Wayback Machine, sorry.

Comment: I edited to fix the link: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/pointline.r