# R: distance between point and line in n-dimensions

Tags: r, vector, distance, algebra, euclidean-distance

I'd like to calculate the distance between a point and a line in any number (i.e., *n*) of dimensions.

An excellent example for 2- and 3- dimensions is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194048/using-r-how-to-calculate-the-distance-from-one-point-to-a-line).

Is there a way to generalize this solution to a greater number of dimensions? I have seen other solutions posted [previously](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168572/distance-from-point-to-n-dimensional-line), but I am not sure exactly how to apply this in R.

Many thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out an answer, working from the solution linked in the original question. Posting the R code here for future readers.

two points, A and B, define the line of interest (here length 10)

```
A <- runif(10, 0.0, 1.0)
B <- runif(10, 0.0, 1.0)
```

determine distance of the following point, P

```
P  <- runif(10, 0.0, 1.0)
```

then work through solution posted in original question

```
pa = P - A
ba = B - A

t = as.vector((pa %*% ba) / (ba %*% ba))
d = (pa - t * ba)
```

last, determine the length of d, the vector of interest by taking the sum of squares of its elements, and then its square root

```
dist = sqrt(sum(d^2))
dist # the solution`
```