# Input distance from data point to regression (using residuals?) into a new dataframe column

Tags: r, regression, data-modeling, linear-regression, modeling

I want to be able to calculate the distance of each individual data point on my plot from my linear regression on that plot, and then store the distances as a new variable (column) in my original dataframe. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910814/calculate-distance-between-regression-line-and-datapoint), that distance value can be found using the residuals of the linear regression. However, I do not know how to apply that to each individual point, and I do not know how to then store the values within the dataframe (if that is even possible).

I created some example data...

```
ex.age <- c(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70)
ex.score <- c(10,9,9,10,8,7,9,6,8,7,6,8,6,5,6,4,5,6,3,5,3)
ex.df <- data.frame(ex.age,ex.score)
```

When graphed, it looks like this...
[image: graph]

I want to then be able to calculate the distance from each point to the regression line, and then store that in a new column, `ex.df$reg.dev`.

How would I be able to accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't apply it to each point. Just do `residuals(your_lm_object)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is grab the residuals from the lm().

```
ex.age <- c(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70)
ex.score <- c(10,9,9,10,8,7,9,6,8,7,6,8,6,5,6,4,5,6,3,5,3)
ex.df <- data.frame(ex.age,ex.score)

ex_model <- lm(ex.score ~ ex.age, data = ex.df)
ex.df$reg.dev <- ex_model$residuals
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ex.age <- c(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70)
ex.score <- c(10,9,9,10,8,7,9,6,8,7,6,8,6,5,6,4,5,6,3,5,3)
ex.df <- data.frame(ex.age,ex.score)

linear_model <- lm(ex.score ~ ex.age, data = ex.df)
ex.df$reg.dev <- linear_model$residuals

ex.df
```